# Loop through category groups

Tags: categories, category, group, loop

I've looped through individual category groups to find each parent/child category, but is there a way to loop through and only show Category Group names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not seeing any obvious ways to access groups directly in Twig. There may be a more direct way, idk — but this should work.

```
{% set categoryGroupNames = [] %}
{% for category in craft.categories %}
    {% set groupName = category.getGroup.name %}
    {% if groupName not in categoryGroupNames %}
        {% set categoryGroupNames = categoryGroupNames|merge([groupName]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for groupName in categoryGroupNames %}
    {{ groupName }}
{% endfor %}
```